cannot using function at button "edit" php
please help me, when i use the edit button its just give me a blank page
fungsi/edit/index.php
}
    if(!empty($_GET['pengguna'])){
        if (isset($_POST['id_login'], $_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['id_member'])) {
            $id_login= htmlentities($_POST['id_login']);
            $user= htmlentities($_POST['user']);
            $pass= md5(htmlentities($_POST['pass']));
            $id_member= htmlentities($_POST['id_member']);
        }
        

        $data = [$user, $pass, $id_member, $id_login];

        $sql = 'UPDATE pengguna SET user=?, pass=?, id_member=? WHERE id_login=?';
        $row = $config -> prepare($sql);
        $row -> execute($data);

        $id = htmlentities($id_login);
        echo '<script>window.location="../../index.php?page=pengguna&uid=' .$id .'&success-edit=edit-data"</script>';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid form submission.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No user specified.';
}


note : database its from table "pengguna"
it contains field (id_login, user, pass, id_member)
pengguna/edit/index.php
}
    if(!empty($_GET['pengguna'])){
        if (isset($_POST['id_login'], $_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['id_member'])) {
            $id_login= htmlentities($_POST['id_login']);
            $user= htmlentities($_POST['user']);
            $pass= md5(htmlentities($_POST['pass']));
            $id_member= htmlentities($_POST['id_member']);
        }
        

        $data = [$user, $pass, $id_member, $id_login];

        $sql = 'UPDATE pengguna SET user=?, pass=?, id_member=? WHERE id_login=?';
        $row = $config -> prepare($sql);
        $row -> execute($data);

        $id = htmlentities($id_login);
        echo '<script>window.location="../../index.php?page=pengguna&uid=' .$id .'&success-edit=edit-data"</script>';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid form submission.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No user specified.';
}


fungsi/view/index.php for show data details in the pop up before update vers
}
                function pengguna(){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pengguna";
                    $row = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                    $row->execute();
                    $hasil = $row->fetchAll();
                    return $hasil;
                }
             
                function pengguna_edit($id){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pengguna WHERE id_login = ?";
                    $row = $this->db-> prepare($sql);
                    $row->execute(array($id));
                    $hasil = $row -> fetch();
                    return $hasil;
                }
        
            }


Have you checked for errors? You can either enable visible error reporting during debugging, or simply look in the PHP error logs.

Why do all your code snippets begin with an unmatched }?

There's no good reason to call htmlentities() when using parameters in a query. htmlentities() should only be used when displaying data on a web page, to prevent XSS.
